# Best way to check the external ble device is still connected to app in swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

Currently I'm managing a flag to check the ble device(External device connect with the app) is connected or not.
(Update flag when connect and disconnect the device)
I want to know the best way to handle this.

Is it possible to check the peripheral for the status?

Comment: If you have connected and haven't had a call to `didDisconnect` then it is still connected...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EAAccessoryManager.shared().connectedAccessories` for getting connected devices.

Comment: But Isn't it only for MFi devices?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[CBCentralManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate)** to monitoring connections with Peripherals.

Answer (score -1):

This method is invoked when a connection succeeded

- parameter central:    The central manager providing this information.
- parameter peripheral: The peripheral that has connected.

```
public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("Bluetooth Manager --> didConnectPeripheral")
}
```

This method is invoked when the peripheral has been disconnected.

- parameter central:    The central manager providing this information
- parameter peripheral: The disconnected peripheral
- parameter error:      The error message

```
public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    print("Bluetooth Manager --> didDisconnectPeripheral")
}
```